# Loading a model from within a Joomla Component view.html.php file

Tags: php, model-view-controller, joomla

I am building a component which has more than one model for functions.
I wish to make a call to a function('getClubs') in a model called 'clubs' ('clubs.php') but I don't know how to connect to this model file from the view.html.php file.
Firstly, is this possible and secondly, how would this be done?

Here is my view.html.php code so far:

```
class SignupViewSignup extends JViewLegacy  {

    public function display($tpl = null) {  
        //make a call to the clubs.php model here
```

Thanks

Comment: -1 from my end: This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful.

Comment: Is this a help site or a school test? Sorry I must be mistaken.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A view is not intended to instantiate any model. That is up to the controller. The controller may provide the view with any model, though.

#### Controller

```
$view = $this->getView('Signup', 'html');
$view->setModel($this->getModel('Signup'), true); // Default model
$view->setModel($this->getModel('Clubs'));
```

#### View / Template

```
$signup = $this->getModel(); // Default model, no parameter needed
$clubs  = $this->getModel('Clubs');
```

Comment: Searching already for hours, in which controller should one put the model loading?

Answer (score 1):

```
$model = $this->getModel('clubs');
```

:) Simple as that! Its not what the file name is but the Model name by the way so like

```
ComponentnameModelClubs
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This works in the controller if I would like to load a model but it doesn't seem to allow me to do this in the view.html file.

Comment: OK will have a look later when I get home!

Comment: Thanks a lot. I get slightly confused with the MVC model of Joomla!

Comment: Ok this really should work in the View as well (see question 7159536 on here)! What error are you getting?